# Foreign Key To Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco, entity-framework-migrations

I'm in VS 2013 and have just created an MVC application.

I'm creating an object I intend to have a foreign key to the AspNetUsers table in the resulting database. The project does have an ApplicationUser (deriving from IdentityUser) that looks like a property-column match with the AspNetUsers table.

How do we properly declare a foreign key to this?

```
public MyObject
{
   public string UserId { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("UserId")]
   public ApplicationUser User { get; set;}

   // other properties
}
```

Now, I modify ApplicationUser to have a collection of MyObjects:

```
public ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
     public virtual ICollection<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }    
}
```

This seems to be how to do one-to-many in EF Code First. However, when I update-database, I'm getting the errors that say Identity members (IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, etc.) have no keys defined. Perhaps those classes were not meant to participate in EF Code First Migrations?

I could go "to the back" and add the foreign key via SQL statements, but if I wanted to update again from Code First, I might get errors (that the database doesn't currently match the older migration or something like that).

How do we properly foreign-key reference those membership tables?

I also tried to create an AspNetUser class with matching properties of the AspNetUsers table. Instead of "public ApplicationUser" on the Client class, I declared "public AspNetUser". Doing this resulted in a migration failure - "Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data loss."

So, what to do?

Comment: I would make a suggestion, avoid using the attributes to define your Entityframework relations.  If you ever plan on using these object outside of a database application the attributes make it difficult to do.

Comment: I've got your same issue, have you solved it?

Answer (score 5):

It is easy to create a one-to-many relationship between `ApplicationUser` and `MyObject` and add a "UserId" foreign key in your `MyObjects` table. What I like about this solution is that it follows EF conventions and there is no need for `[ForeignKey]` attribute in your model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public int MyObjectId { get; set; }

    public string MyObjectName { get; set; }

    // other properties

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyObject>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.ApplicationUser)
            .WithMany(t => t.MyObjects)
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("UserId"));
    }
}
```

Notice the use of Fluent API to create a "UserId" foreign key in your `MyObjects` table. This solution would still work without adding the Fluent API, but then your foreign key column would be named "ApplicationUser_Id" in your `MyObjects` table by convention.

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following: In the `ApplicationUser` class, add a `ForeignKey` attribute,

```
public ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual ICollection<MyCustomUser> MyCustomUsers{ get; set; }    
}
```

and in your model where you want to track to which user it belongs,

```
public MyObject {
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

You don't need to store the whole `ApplicationUser` instance in the `MyObject` class, and the `UserID` will be generated automatically. It is important that is is of type `string`, as is the `ID` of the `ApplicationUser`!

Comment: I prefer to avoid using attributes to define EF relations as @BlackICE suggests and would avoid using `[ForeignKey]`. My solution uses Fluent API to define the relation, which I feel is much cleaner. Of course, the Fluent API is unnecessary if you want the foreign key to be named "ApplicationUser_Id" by convention.

Answer (score 1):

```
public MyObject
{
   .. other properties

   [MaxLength(128), ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
   public virtual string UserId { get; set; }

   public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for the last line, `public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }`?  Shouldn't the ForeignKey to ApplicationUser in the line above that be sufficient?

Comment: @ToastyMallows, the last line gives me a navigation property in linq queries. But you are right, leave it out and you will still get the foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

this is also an alternative way for @kimbaudi suggestion. With this, you don't need to define mapping key attribute instead you can use your own defined Model attribute.

```
public class MyObject
{
   public string UserId { get; set; }


   public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    // other properties
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{ 
    public virtual ICollection<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }      

}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyObject>()
        .HasRequired(po => po.User)
        .WithMany(a => a.MyObjects)
        .HasForeignKey(po => po.UserId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET Identity classes doesn't use attributes to define the relations, they expect the relations to be configured by the DbContext.

The default DbContext used with ASP.NET Identity, `IdentityDbContext<TUser>` includes the configuration. So if you make your DbContext class inherit from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` you should be all set.

**Update**

If you still get error: "Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data loss."
then do:

```
get Update-Database -Force
```

If you still get error messages about IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, etc. have no keys defined
then you most likely are overriding the `OnModelCreating` method in your DbContext without calling the base method first. Add a call to the base like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelbuilder);
    // your code here
}
```

**End of Update**

If you don't want to inherit from `IdentityDbContext` you need to add some configuration for the Identity classes. One way to do this is by overriding `OnModelCreating`. This is where `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` configure the entity framework mappings. 
If you add this to your DbContext class it should set up the mappings you need.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
}
```

Comment: I tried to inherit IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> - doesn't work. I still get the same error when I try to migrate.

Comment: Updated my answer with some information on what to do depending on which error you get after making your DbContext inherit from the IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> class

Comment: I got the error ".. result in lost data" when I created the AspNetUser class manually and included it in the migration. I also got that error when I overrode OnModelCreating with the 3 FK statements without inheriting IdentityDbContext<TUser>. When I inherited IdentityDbContext<TUser> as documentation states to do, I still get those "no keys defined" errors - I thought that IdentityDbContext<TUser> declared those keys, which would take care of everything.

Comment: Interestingly, I just tried to start a new MVC project. The first thing I did was run Update-Database in the PM console. So I didn't create any new POCO objects or edit any existing models the project generated. I know there's the ApplicationDbContext already in there which inherited IdentityDbContext<TUser>. Running Update-Database gave me those validation errors where "has no keys defined." Microsoft may have taken those FK attributes out recently.

Comment: I also try all possible solution of StackOverFlow, i also cannot set foreign key to the AspNetUsers table by Code-First, the new ASP.NET Identity is a joke.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have it backwards. Maybe try something like:

```
public MyCustomUser : IUser
{
   public string Id { get; set; }

   public string FavoriteHairColor { get; set;}
}

public ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
     public virtual ICollection<MyCustomUser> MyCustomUsers{ get; set; }    
}
```

I'm going from memory here so I might be a little off. Anyway, the important things is to have your EF user class inherit from IUser.

Comment: I'm not trying to inherit MyCustomUser. I'm trying to have MyObject to have a foreign key to the ApplicationUser.

Comment: How to achieve this by Fluent API?

Comment: @MichaelMao - Please take a look at my solution on how to achieve this using Fluent API. Actually, you don't need Fluent API if you're happy with the foreign key name defaulting to "ApplicationUser_Id" by EF convention. However, if you want to customize the name of the foreign key, then it is necessary.