# How to add a foreign key reference to ASP.Net MVC 5 Identity?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a new ASP.NET MVC 5.1 project using the ASP.Net Identity.
It seems reliable and promise, but today i spend almost 9 hours to do a simple things if using SQL.

My problem is, i cannot create a table via CodeFirst with foreign key reference to the default AspNetUsers table.

For example:
I have create a table named - **Address**

```
   public class Address
    {
        [Key]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string MyAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

But how can i create a foreign key reference to **AspNetUsers**?

I try replace the property above by

```
public IdentityUser MyAddress { get; set; }
// Or
public virtual IdentityUser MyAddress { get; set; }
// Or
public virtual ApplicationUser MyAddress { get; set; }
```

But all of them still show error:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

MiaPos.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. 
MiaPos.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. 
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined. 
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

I also try override the **OnModelCreating** from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20106318/83952)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
}
```

But when i run **Add-Migration**, it create the IdentityUserLogin, IdentityRole, IdentityUserRole tables and it duplicate, just the prefix is different. (AspNet<->Identity)

Finally i do it by SQL in 10 seconds, but i just want to know why i cannot do in CodeFirst?
And why so hard to do a such things from ***Microsoft 2014 New Technology***.

[image]

Comment: You can check this: https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample

Comment: thanks you Gábor Plesz, i will check this ASAP.

Comment: Hi Gábor Plesz, i just check the sample. I found the answer. So i answer my question.

Comment: Just posted an answer to a similar question, if that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104289/foreign-key-to-microsoft-aspnet-identity-entityframework-identityuser/29010130#29010130

Answer (score 28):

Thanks you **Gábor Plesz** for comment above.

I found the solution.

The ApplicationUser class who inherit **IdentityUser** (which create AspNetUsers table)  should create a ICollection property of the child class (child table).

e.g.

```
public virtual ICollection<ToDo> ToDoes { get; set; }
```

So the **ToDo** class can be reference to  **ApplicationUser**

Highly recommend have a look the sample as **Gábor Plesz** said.

[image]

Comment: Please mark your answer as the correct answer to help others

Comment: @Cheung how to add foreign key relationship if my entities are in another class library project and Identity tables are in web project? Please let me know if you have any idea?

Comment: Would I need to change the IdentityUser to ApplicationUser, whereever IdentityUser 
 was used?

Answer (score 28):

You can do like this. because sometime you may need 1-1 connection

```
 public class AnotherTable
    {
        [Key]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: this should be the right answer !
for not 1-1 , you create a third table , which contains both AnotherTable ID and ApplicationUser ID

Comment: @MichaelMao Simply by convention. Name your child class foreign key string property to 'ApplicationUserId' this will be the foreign key by convention. EntityName + Id. Same is valid for primary key. 'Id' will always be the primarykey.

Answer (score 2):

If you really wanna create a table named Address instead of creating a property named Address to generated as a column into AspNetUsers table do the following (obs: in this case i am assuming that a user can have many address):

1. At your Address class:

   ```
   public class Address
   {
       public string MyAddress { get; set; }

       // referencing the AspNetUsers table ( ApplicationUser.cs)
       public string UserId { get; set; }
       public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Your ApplicationUser Class:

   ```
   public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
   ```
3. Within your DBContext in OnModelCreating method do the following ( fluent API ):

   ```
   builder.Entity<Address>()
                 .HasOne(c => c.User)
                 .WithMany(x => x.Addresses)
                 .HasForeignKey(f => f.UserId)
                 .HasConstraintName("UserId")
                 .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                 .IsRequired();
   ```

OBS: Don´t forget adding above the OnModelCreating method this line of code:

```
public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
```

After it run those commands within your Package Manager Console:

```
Add-Migrations UserAddress
```

and after:

```
Update-Database.
```

But, if you wanna just inclued a new property to the AspNet Users just create at your ApplicationUser.cs file/class this property:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

and run the same commands for your PMC:

```
Add-Migration UserAddress
```

after:

```
Update-Database
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would I need to change the IdentityUser to ApplicationUser, whereever IdentityUser 
 was used?