# Create a foreign key to a table that is outside the scope of my Entity Framework Data Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

For our ASP.NET Web Application using MVC 5, we are using the built-in ASP.NET Identities system.  By default this generates a bunch of useful tables for us, including AspNetUsers.  Our Entity Framework model which we've created includes entities which need to use the AspNetUsers.Id column as a foreign key constraint.

It doesn't appear to be possible to create a foreign key to a table not included in our Entity Framework Data Model, but never the less I need to do *something* to make this foreign key constraint possible, without screwing up the default Identities API.

One idea I had was to create like a "UserProxies" entity in our data model.  Then whenever a new User is created and added to AspNetUsers, he/she is also added to our UserProxies table.  That way we have a "copy" of the AspNetUsers data in our data model, and can confidently make reference to the UserProxies.Id column and know that it matches up to an AspNetUsers.Id.

This kind of sucks though because it's just duplicating data.

The other idea I had was, just ignore the foreign key constraint and always trust that the relationship is valid.  This also sucks (but may be acceptable for what we're doing if there is no solution that doesn't involve re-inventing the wheel).

Comment: check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447313/how-do-i-integrate-membership-tables-with-entity-framework-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx) post from msdn

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx

or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297097/how-to-add-a-foreign-key-reference-to-asp-net-mvc-5-identity) one

> [How to add a foreign key reference to ASP.Net MVC 5 Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297097/how-to-add-a-foreign-key-reference-to-asp-net-mvc-5-identity)

Comment: please also quote from the sites. the links might go down in the future.

Comment: i meant to quote the content. not the url ;)