# foreign key to application user id throwing key errors when updating database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2, ef-fluent-api

I'm using code first to create a foreign key on `YogaSpace` that links the `ApplicationUsers` id to `ApplicationUserRefId` in the `YogaSpace` class. So every time I create and insert a new `YogaSpace` it fills the `ApplicationUser` id with the id of the person logged in. And I want it to be a one-to-many where the `YogaSpace` object can be many for one `ApplicationUser` id. But I'm getting key errors.

```
public class YogaSpace
{
    // for a one-to-one relationship
    // great tutorial on code-first
    //http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

    [Index (IsUnique = true)]
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int YogaSpaceId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ApplicationUserRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserRefId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my `ApplicationUser` class

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{   
    //other members left out to save space
    public virtual ICollection<YogaSpace> YogaSpaces { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Here are all the errors. When updating the database, it's throwing related to keys.

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> GiftExchange.DataLayer.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' >has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   GiftExchange.DataLayer.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' >has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

UPDATE!
I tried overriding the class that its asking me to create a key for but it still doesn't work

```
public class TestIdentityUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin
{
    [Key]
    public override string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

I tried adding the keys using fluent api found in this link
[[User in Entity type MVC5 EF6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913447/user-in-entity-type-mvc5-ef6][1])

In my `YogaSpaceContext` I included

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
    }
```

and it seemed to remove the no key defined errors from the package manager for updating the database.
But how would I implement it in code first?

Comment: The fluent API *is* code first. You can't apply attributes to base classes through derived classes, so the fluent API is all you've got.

Comment: Why not modelbuild for the ApplicationUser . 
`modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasKey<string>(_ => _.Id);` I was having similar problems and that worked. However i am not sure why it worked, which is bothering me

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following: In the `ApplicationUser` class, add a `ForeignKey` attribute,

```
public ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual ICollection<YogaSpace> YogaSpaces { get; set; } 

    // other properties
}
```

and in the `YogaSpace` model where you want to track to which `ApplicationUser` it belongs,

```
public class YogaSpace{
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

You don't need to store the whole `ApplicationUser` instance in the `YogaSpace` class, and the `UserID` will be generated automatically. It is important that is is of type `string`, as is the `ID` of the `ApplicationUser`!

(Duplicated my answer to [Foreign Key To Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104289/foreign-key-to-microsoft-aspnet-identity-entityframework-identityuser/29010130#29010130))

Answer (score -2):

Actually I think you should try something different if you're using code-first, for example..

Your ApplicationUser class:

```
class ApplicationUser
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public ICollection<YogaSpace> YogaSpaces { get; set; }
}
```

You have a collection of YogaSpaces, and then, your YogaSpace class like:

```
public class YogaSpace
{
   public int Id { get; set; };
   public int AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And EF will create the right tables for you.

PS: Not tested, but that's the way.

Comment: What I want to do is simple. When I create a new YogaSpace I want it to have a OwnerId that belongs to the person logged in. Then when I search for YogaSpaces I can fetch all YogaSpaces that belong to that person. Ex. I have an Id in applicationuser of 23 and I want to search for all YogaSpaces with a property value ('someId') of 23. So everytime I create a new YogaSpace it inserts the id from applicationuser into the table. I can do it manually but it seems like code first or identity 2 would have something that supports that?????

Comment: `Id` property is coming from inherited object `IdentityUser`.