# How to make relationship between tables in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, model-view-controller

I use "AspIdentity" in the project. In project all standard models of "AspIdentity"
and one model "Post". I would like each post to have its ApplicationUser and each ApplicationUser have its own collection of posts. And already have one database in which there is a table that stores information about users.

I tried to create tables, data context and database independently, but I don't find any information but I didn't find information about the case close to mine.

Post model:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationUser model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        Posts = new List<Post>();
    }
}
```

I expect to see a data context in the response and a query with which to create a table of posts.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104289/foreign-key-to-microsoft-aspnet-identity-entityframework-identityuser

Comment: The point would be in which DbContext they are mapped. If you have a separate BlogContext and ApplicationContext then I don't think EF will let you map this. Even if SQL has no problem with it (cross database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the **OnModelCreating** method in your DbContext class (presumably ApplicationDbContext). In the overridden method, establish the relationship between the classes. The following is the sample code that should solve your problem:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Posts)
                .WithRequired(e => e.ApplicationUser)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.ApplicationUserId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```